# Error installing npm bluetooth-hci-socket

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, npm-install, node-gyp

I am trying to add bluetooth-hci-socket to node.js as an admin in windows

**npm install bluetooth-hci-socket** gives me:

[image]

**My Question: What does failed at the bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.0 install: 'node-gyp rebuild' mean? And how to I fix it?**

Thank you!

**Extra info:**

As perquisites, and without errors, I ran:

*npm install --global --production windows-build-tools*

*npm install -g node-gyp*

and changed the driver settings with Zadig (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mL9B8wuEdms)

Comment: I am running into this issue. Please let me know if you ever found a fix.